# Allow '+' on Identity Username

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, identity

I am using `Aspnet.Identity.EntityFramework 2.2.1`.

I am trying to register a user with the **username equal the email** leonardo+felipe@gmail.com, however
When email has this "+" character, Identity Framework does not allow:

[image]

This raises an error where the username field only allows letters and digits, but I need to save an email that has this "+" character. If I remove the "+" character, it is possible to register successfully.

How to override this Identity UserName validation?

Comment: The error is about your **username**, not the email field.

Comment: @CodeCaster, it's because the email is the same of username, so I need the username has permission to save with + sign. Maybe it's not possible?

Comment: It is possible and explained in the linked duplicate.